# Windows Forms - ChildForm in panel is zoomed in

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have this code to show the childform within the panel:

```cs
private Form activeForm = null;
private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
{
    if (activeForm != null)
    {
        activeForm.Close();
    }
    activeForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    panelChildForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
    panelChildForm.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
    labelVersion.BringToFront();
}
```

The size of the panel and form are exactly the same (the form is a bit larger due to the border, but the borderless size is exactly as the panel). But for some reason, it seems like the form zoomes in when I open it and I can't figure it out.

Comment: That's what you'd expect to happen.  The form itself no longer determines it size, it is now fixed by the panel size.  If the form deals gracefully with a changing window size then that will be visible while docked in the panel as well.  Or it could be that your app is dpiAware, and the form rescales accordingly.

Comment: Well the strange thing is: I got it to work now. I went ahead and changed the font of the form to 10 and then back to 8 and now it fits perfectly. I don't really understand what happend there but I'm glad I got it to work now.

Comment: Ah, that explains it.  Font is an "ambient" property, if it is not explicitly set then it uses the font of the parent.  In other words, it used the font of the Panel.  And if it is not set (normally it isn't), it used the font of the Panel's parent, etcetera.  This is typically highly desirable, it ensures that all controls use the same font.

Comment: alrighttttt that explains it then. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the strange thing is: I got it to work now. I went ahead and changed the font of the form to 10 and then back to 8 and now it fits perfectly. I don't really understand what happend there but I'm glad I got it to work now.